# Import Multiple Excel Sheets with Different Sheets Name into Single SQL table using Script task in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

I want to import multiple excel files with different sheets name into one SQL table using script task in SSIS.

Please help me.
I am very Thankful to you.

Comment: Need more information. what have you tried ?

Comment: I had created 4 variables in SSIS like, FileName- Contains the file path, Folderpath- Contains the path of the directory, FileExtension Contains the extension of file(.xls), Sheetname- Contains Sheet name(Sheet1$). then i put a script task and a data flow task in a for each loop container and try to write some script for reading the sheet name dynamically but i m not getting the logic how to read sheet name

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample VB code that I had in a script task to get the sheet names and store it in a Variable of Data type object. Then use a For Each Variable Enumerator to iterate through User::ExcelSchema.

```
 Public Sub Main()
    Dim excelFilePath As String =                Dts.Variables("User::SourceDataPathAndFile").Value.ToString()
    Dim strCn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
       "Data Source=" + excelFilePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"
    Dim dtTables As DataTable
    Dim aTableNames As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
    Dim tableName As String
    Dim cn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(strCn)
    cn.Open()
    dtTables = cn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
    For Each row As DataRow In dtTables.Rows
        tableName = row("TABLE_NAME").ToString()
        aTableNames.Add(tableName)
        End If

    Next
    cn.Close()
    Dts.Variables("User::ExcelSchema").Value = aTableNames
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but can you please tell me variables SourceDataPathAndFile, and ExcelSchema. what value they store

Comment: SourceDataPathAndFile would be your folder path + file name essentially path to the file. ExcelSchema would be an object data type  which has the sheet names in the file.